# position being shifted depending on the length of text

Tags: html, css

i am making a css banner for images on for my site. I have the basic ribbon created but it's acting odd and i can't see to find out whats going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/5jqpasyo/

Html:

```
<body>
    <div> 
      <span class="top"></span> 
      <span class="bottom"></span>
      <span class="ribbon-text">TRENDING</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Css:

```
.top {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-45deg)
}

.bottom{
position:absolute;
left:160px;
top:60px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(45deg)
}

.ribbon-text{
position:absolute;
left:150px;
top:50px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

depending on the size of the ribbon's text the position gets shifted. For example "TRENDING" works perfectly as i expected it to. but if i change it to "SALE" it's not in the correct position any more.

and if i add something shorter or longer it constantly changes position. ny idea as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

By giving the `div` a class and `ribbon-text` a width i could then position that to fit the top and bottom ribbon edge to edge then center align the text within that so it now centers the text no matter the length (aslong as its not longer than the width)

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/a5g81umL/)**

```
.ribbon-text{
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    left:130px;
    width:130px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index:100;
}
.ribbon-block p{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same thing without need of extra class on div and extra paragraph.
Here's simplified version:

```
.top {
position:absolute;
left:130px;
top:30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-45deg)
}

.bottom{
position:absolute;
left:160px;
top:60px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(45deg)
}

.ribbon-text{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:130px;
    width:130px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index:100;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Cheers